# Issue when using leftPos in jquery scrollleft

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am developing a small box which slide the content for a web. I use following method for slide the content

```js
var slider_array_length = $('.see-work').length;
var slider_inner_width = slider_array_length * 32.5;
$('.see_work_slider').css({
  width: slider_inner_width + "vw"
});

$('.right_controller').click(function() {
  var leftPos = $('.see_work_slider_wrapper').scrollLeft();
  $('.see_work_slider_wrapper').animate({
    scrollLeft: leftPos + 440
  }, 400);
});

$('.left_controller').click(function() {
  var leftPos = $('.see_work_slider_wrapper').scrollLeft();
  $('.see_work_slider_wrapper').animate({
    scrollLeft: leftPos - 440
  }, 400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="see_work_slider_wrapper">
  <div class="see_work_slider">
    <div class="see-work">
      <div class="see-work-img background"></div>
      <h6 class="left_controller lc_clz"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> prev</h6>
      <h6 class="right_controller">next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h6>
    </div>

    <div class="see-work">
      <div class="see-work-img background"></div>
      <h6 class="left_controller lc_clz"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> prev</h6>
      <h6 class="right_controller">next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h6>
    </div>

    <div class="see-work">
      <div class="see-work-img background"></div>
      <p></p>
      <h6 class="left_controller lc_clz"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> prev</h6>
      <h6 class="right_controller">next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h6>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

(32.5 is the width of 'see-work' div)
The problem is for go to 'previous' content I should go to 'next' content before 'previous' content. Also when it load last content it doesn't load first content again. This doesn't work as a loop. I want to load content as a loop. When we load last content if we click 'next' it should load the first content again.

Could someone please tell me what is wrong and how I fix it?

Comment: Share some HTML code? It is hard to understand without html code!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited question and attached the HTML code now

Comment: I created a functionality but that is not not working properly in you jquery code, It will be great if you add the css as well. I will try modifying you code.